# External hard drives stopped working after sudden shutdown on Windows

Tags: windows, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

After suddenly shutting down the computer, two external USB hard drives I had connected have stopped working in windows. They are WD Elements and Seagate STGX5000400. Now when I connect them to that computer they make some sound periodically but I don't see them show up. I have another computer with linux in which they work correctly. I've used gparted to check the hard drives but it didn't repair them. I also restarted windows with the drives unplugged and then plugged them again, but that didn't work either. How can I use the hard drives again in windows without having to format them or lose any data?

Comment: Was the sudden shutdown caused by electrical problems?

Comment: I unintentionally unplugged one of the cables of the SSD and the computer shutdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume these drives are USB connected?
Try this:

- Disconnect them from the computer. Disconnect the power from both drives (if they have a separate power-supply.)
- Boot the computer in Windows.
- After Windows is fully booted, reboot.
  This is let Windows realize that the drives are really no longer there.
- Boot again into Windows.
- Make sure the drive is ON (if it has a separate power-supply). Then reconnect the USB cable to the computer.
  With any luck the computer will now recognize the drive. Do a "Check Disk" in Windows just to be safe. Windows may have to "fix" a couple of things that Linux/GParted isn't bothered by.
- Same procedure with the 2nd disk.

Comment: This worked the second time I tried it.